# How to use grep to return entire string if pattern is NULL?

Tags: r, grepl

I am currently building an R Shiny app and have to incorporate some string searching functionality into it. If my search box is empty, I'd like the original dataframe to be returned and if the search box is populated then just filter the dataframe to all rows that contain the string.

Ideally, I'd like to know if this is possible without having to use any conditionals. I have rewritten a basic example of my code below in base R but `NULL` seems to be an invalid pattern argument for the `grepl` function.

```
search <- NULL
test <- iris %>% filter(is.null(search) | grepl(search,Species))
```

This code works as intended when `search <- "s"` but I want to know if there is a way to just return `iris` when `search <- NULL`?

Comment: Shouldn't `iris %>% filter(is.null(search))` work? The `pattern` of `grepl` needs a character string (`?grep` - pattern - character string containing a regex)  The `NULL` is not a string, but a class of "NULL"

Comment: Even if your code worked it’s not at all obvious why it would be better than using a conditional.

Comment: That does work but `search` is a reactive value technically so in the cases where `search` is not `NULL`, I'd want to filter `iris` to all rows where `grepl(search,Species)` is `TRUE`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph essentially I'm trying to minimize the size of my code. In my actual code, there's a lot more parameters in the `filter` so I don't want to have to double the length of code by using a conditional.

Comment: @AnirudhNambiar Minimising the size of your code is only a good idea if you’re not producing worse code as a result. Smaller code *can* be better code but only if you’re not destroying readability in the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without conditionals by giving `search` the default pattern `""` or `".*"` instead of `NULL`. For example, this will return the expected subset of `iris`:

```r
search <- "virginica"
filter(iris, grepl(search, Species))
```

And this will return the entire dataframe:

```r
search <- ""
filter(iris, grepl(search, Species))
```

Comment: Yup this is the best implementation for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don’t avoid conditionals when they’re the correct solution.

If you want to avoid an intermediate assignment, you can:

```
test <- iris %>% filter(if (is.null(search)) TRUE else grepl(search, Species))
```

But I’d prefer avoiding the filter entirely, by being explicit:

```
test <- if (is.null(search)) {
    iris
} else {
    iris %>% filter(grepl(search, Species))
}
```